# Can someone explain this awk script to me?

Tags: awk

I was doing some research on linux and I came across this awk script:

```
$ awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && !($1 == "nobody" && $3 == 65534) { SUM+=1 } END { print SUM }' /etc/passwd
```

It will get the number of local user accounts by counting users with UID greater or equal to 1000 and ignoring special nobody account.

However, I do not understand the code. Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: It must be noted that the script ignores the user `nobody` *only if* its user id equals to `65534`.

Comment: Click the [tag:awk] tag, then click "Learn more..."

Answer (score 5):

Based on your shown code, following explanation may help you here. Following is only for explanation purposes for running command use OP's actual one.

```
awk -F: '          ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as colon here.
$3 >= 1000 && !($1 == "nobody" && $3 == 65534) { 
                   ##Checking condition if 3rd column is greater than or equal to 1000 AND either 1st column is distinct from nobody OR 3rd is distinct from 6553 then do following.
SUM+=1             ##Adding 1 to SUM here.
} 
END {              ##Starting END section of this program from here.
  print SUM        ##Printing SUM here.
}' /etc/passwd     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Also for learning more about `awk` you could refer `man awk` too OR you could check [this useful link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.txt) too.

***NOTE:*** As per Ed sir's nice suggestion for improving your attempted code(consider following too):

> and print SUM should be print SUM+0 to correctly handle the case where
> the condition is never true. You should also never use all-upper-case
> for user-defined variable names to avoid clashing with built-in
> variable names.

Comment: @Ong Bang Rui, Hello, could you please do let me know if my answer was helpful to you? Thank you.